# Reason: (noSuchName) There is no such variable name in this MIB. in snmpset

Tags: snmp

I have try the snmpwalk command to see all the variables in mib,
I can read any variable without any errors, but when i try snmpset i get an error, for example:

```
     sudo snmpset -v1 -c public 127.0.0.1 iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.4.0 s "sahra@mail.com"
     Error in packet.
     Reason: (noSuchName) There is no such variable name in this MIB.
     Failed object: iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.4.0
```

Comment: when i use snmp v2c it tells me :
 
  Error in packet.
  Reason: noAccess

Comment: problem solved
whoever face this problem , fellow this link 
http://ajitabhpandey.info/2007/01/setting-up-snmp/

Comment: Post how you resolved it as an answer and then accept it.

Comment: No reason to use sudo for an snmpset!